# Write unit test for NodeJs agenda job processor

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai, agenda

I'm using agenda framework for job scheduling link https://github.com/agenda/agenda

Scheduling a job it sends email to user, it's working fine, but I want to write unit test for current code. Any help appreciated

this jobs runs as process for example node jobname

```
module.exports = function (agenda) {

agenda.define('sendemail', function (task, done) {

 // Sending email logic here

})


// Success event when job run successfully, 
agenda.on('success:sendemail', function (task) {

// send email to admin job run successfully
})

// Fail event when job failed 
agenda.on('fail:sendemail', function (err, task) {

// send email to admin job failed

 })


// Run sendemail job
agenda.on('ready', function () {

  agenda.schedule('in 5 seconds', 'sendemail', {
    time: new Date()
  })

 agenda.start()
})

}
```

sendemail has different state success,failure
For sending email using AWS SES service.
Want to write unit test for above code and want to verify whether job succeed or failed.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [test cases](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/tree/master/test) by [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) itself.

Example:
https://github.com/agenda/agenda/blob/master/test/job.js.